# How to use Rack::Attack with a cache prefix?

Tags: security, caching, rack, middleware, rate-limiting

We're running several apps against the same Memcached, so I'd like to configure different prefixes for all apps using Rack::Attack. By default, several apps would overwrite each others' cache.

I've seen the [prefix accessor in `Rack::Attack::Cache`](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/blob/master/lib/rack/attack/cache.rb#L5) and there's even a [low-level spec for it](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/blob/master/spec/rack_attack_cache_spec.rb#L57) but there are no examples on how to use it.

According to the [README](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) and the [introductory blogpost](http://www.kickstarter.com/backing-and-hacking/rack-attack-protection-from-abusive-clients), I never have to deal with `Rack::Attack::Cache` but always with the higher-level `Rack::Attack`.

So, how can two or more apps use the same memcached for Rack::Attack without overwriting each others' cache keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Rack::Attack.cache.prefix = "custom-prefix"
```

Rack::Attack.cache is an instance of the Rack::Attack::Cache class.